# Can we create Mysql views from AWS Read Replica?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

I need to be able to create custom views from an AWS RDS read replica. Is this something we could achieve without making any modifications to parameter groups

I know the fact that we could make a read replica writable by adjusting the value of read_only parameter to 0 in parameter groups.

Is it possible to create custom views from a read replica without making any changes to parameter groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two possible ways to add views to an RDS replica.

The simplest is to create those views on the master, but access them from the replica. MySQL doesn't materialize views, so this doesn't have a resource cost in the master.

But if that doesn't suit your needs, the only alternative is to set `read_only` to 0 in the parameter group.  After adding the views, you can change it back to the default so that the replica does not remain writable.  Updating this specific parameter value should not require a restart to apply it.

Comment: @Micheal however this requires restart to apply changes

Comment: Changing *which* parameter group is attached to an instance always requires a restart.  Editing a parameter in a group only requires a restart for certain parameters, and the `read_only`parameter should not require a restart.